# How to open an alert dialog in an another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alertdialog

How do I open a dialog in a new activity from a non-activity?  I have a service that runs a countdown timer and when the count down timer finishes i would like for it to open a dialog in the main activity.  I cant seem to figure this out. I've tried normally setting up the alert dialog which didn't work and I've tried sending intents with extras and bundles and still no luck.  I've searched on Google for help and tired the solution from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839159/how-can-show-alert-dialog-in-another-activity).

```
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Log.i(TAG, "Timer finished");
            cdt.start();
            showNotification();
            addpoints();
            savepref();
            Intent intent = new Intent(BroadcastService.this,  MainActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("alert_icon_res_id", android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
            bundle.putString("alert_title", "Some Title");
            bundle.putString("alert_message", "Some message");
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            startActivity(intent);





        }
    };

    cdt.start();
}
```

Main activity code here:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startService(new Intent(this, BroadcastService.class));
    Log.i(TAG, "Started service");

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (b != null && b.containsKey("alert_icon_res_id")) {
        int icon = b.getInt("alert_icon_res_id");
        String title = b.getString("alert_title");
        String message = b.getString("alert_message");

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(icon)
                .setTitle(title).setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).create().show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `OnFinish` you have not put the bundle in the intent.

Try this:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

bundle.putInt("alert_icon_res_id", android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);

bundle.putString("alert_title", "Some Title");

bundle.putString("alert_message", "Some message");

intent.putExtras(bundle);   // add this line

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: this works!! but it keeps opening up new activities on top of each other now.